# unable to add dimens.xml directory to values

Tags: android-studio, android-xml

I have to add a directory(dimens.xml) to values,since i have three dimens.xml files for different screen sizes.I cant find it even after creating it.Kindly help.
I need something like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwc70.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create different **values** folder according to the screen size and inside that put  dimens.xml file. Follow this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: you can create `values-sw600dp` and `values-sw720dp-land` and in that create dimen.xml file

Comment: Change the view from **Android** to **Project** you will be able to see it.Check this image http://developer.android.com/images/tools/projectview01.png

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio automatically displays the resource folder for you, you don't actually have to create a separate folder if you're looking in Android view.  Create your default dimens.xml with no qualifiers.  When you create another dimens.xml (same file name), you can add qualifiers.  For example, I just created two dimens.xml files, one without qualifiers and one with the Screen Width qualifier.  For the one with the Screen Width qualifier, I defined the screen width as 820 (it assumes dp).  Once created, in Android view, you'll see a dimens folder inside the values folder, and the two dimens.xml files, one with the qualifier in parentheses, inside of it.